# Unclear System.Exception in Windows Phone app

Tags: c#, exception, windows-phone-8.1

Sometimes in my log i find this strange exception:

> System.Exception: Packets in the frame are inconsistent. Either
>   pointer ids are not unique or there is a discrepancy in timestamps,
>   frame ids, pointer types or source devices.
>
> Packets in the frame are inconsistent. Either pointer ids are not
>   unique or there is a discrepancy in timestamps, frame ids, pointer
>   types or source devices.

There is no stacktrace and i found pretty nothing in google by this error, except  of this codes of this error: 0x80400004 and winerror.h -2143289340.

Did anyone had this problem too and fixed it or at least some way to detect cause of this error?